# Zend Framework 2 without MVC

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm currently using Zend Framework 2 for all my web tier development using the MVC module that's shipped with the framework.

However, I want to implement my business logic in a separate layer, call it the business tier which is a non HTTP layer and expose it through AMQP, and I'd like to reuse my knowledge of PHP for implementing this. Since there is a lot of "stuff" that I need in this business layer such as configuration, a service manager, database access, etc, etc, I'd like to use all the goodies shipped with Zend Framework 2 for this.

Are there any examples or tutorials out there on how to build a Zend Framework 2 application that is not build for the web tier and doesn't require the MVC module?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any examples myself on this honestly.

From my perspective the php 'worker' might look something like this.

In this example I'm assuming you're using composer.

```
<?php

//use composer to autoload all zf2 modules you need
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//setup service manager
//...
//setup configuration code
//...
//setup database code
//...

while( true ){

$stuff = waitForAMPQMessage();

processMessage( $stuff );

}
```

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hi.Thanks. I will definitely be using composer. I was kinda hoping that there was another type of Application. E.g. the Mvc & Console modules have an Application base class. But the thing I'm trying to achieve is kinda like a Server application but there doesn't seem to be a server Application base class. Your solution makes total sense though.. :)

Comment: Well, the whole mvc module CAN be made to do what you want. The problem is that YOU would have to configure it. Currently, it's configured for web/console stuff. You would really have to understand the framework more to do this I think. I'm not in a position of understanding to do it either.

Answer (score 0):

I had used ZF2 to create many command line tools - cron jobs that integrates with the ZF2 web interface , it was pretty easy and powerful to use Zend console component or Symfony console  component .

this example was built on top of symfony2 console : https://gist.github.com/tawfekov/5858354

this example was sending sms , printing pdf files , sending emails as reports to managers and performing tasks on remote apis to

every time i need to run cron job , or manually run a task :

`php Tool.php Remote:Read`

`php Tool.php Pdf:Canel`

`php Tool.php Sms:Id 1985` sending sms by id

these are defined in the task classes , you create your own type of  it